# Click on span elements that is added after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, loaded

I have a div. After a click on a word, the div gets some spans.
The Code:

```
<div id="show-data">
  <span>Erprobung</span> 
  <span>Probe</span> 
  <span>Prüfung</span> 
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

My problem: I want to click on the new span-tags too, but it doesn't work for me. Here is my code:

```
$('$data-show').on('mouseover','span',function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

```html
<div id="show-data"></div>
```

What is the solution to this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: Typo. `$data-show` should be `#show-data`. Also, you say you want a click handler, so `mouseover` should be `click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#show-data` instead of `$data-show` and [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event instead of [`mouseover()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event.

```js
$('#show-data').on('click','span',function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
    
var count = 0;
$('button').on('click', function(){
  count = count+1;
  $('#show-data').append('<span>Test'+count+'</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="show-data">
    <span>Erprobung</span> 
    <span>Probe</span> 
    <span>Prüfung</span> 
    <span>Test</span>
    </div>
    <button>Add Span</button>
```

Comment: Okay, it works now! I copied your script and it worked. Thank you so much!